# Plotly + Ipywidget to html

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, ipywidgets

I have a sample Python script below that generates a simple plotly graph and widget. Where the widget selector modifies the colour of the line.

This works great in a jupyter notebook or VSCode Interactive Python section. Unfortunately when exporting to HTML I am losing the interactivity.

My script is below

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from ipywidgets import widgets

PURPLE = 'rgba(96, 74, 123, 1)'
RED = 'rgba(192, 80, 77, 1)'

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [1, 10, 'purple'],
        [2, 20, 'purple'],

        [1, 10, 'red'],
        [2, 20, 'red'],
    ],
    columns=['xcol', 'ycol', 'colourselector']
)

colour_selector = widgets.Dropdown(
    description='colour selector:',
    options=df['colourselector'].unique().tolist(),
    value='red',
)

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=df['xcol'], y=df['ycol'], opacity=0.75, marker={'color': RED})
fig = go.FigureWidget(
    data=[trace1]
)

def select_col(_):
    if colour_selector.value == 'purple':
        return PURPLE
    if colour_selector.value == 'red':
        return RED


def response(_):
    """ overlay callable """
    with fig.batch_update():
        fig.data[0].marker = {'color': select_col(colour_selector.value)}


colour_selector.observe(response)
col_sel = widgets.HBox([colour_selector])
widgets.VBox([col_sel, fig])
```

This generates the graph below:
[image]

Where the dropdown enables me to change the colour of the line.

I then export it to html with the following command:

```bash
./env/scripts/jupyter nbconvert --execute ./notebooks/lfs.tsgen.ipynb --to html
```

Which creates an html output with identical output; however, graph interactivity is no longer supported.

I am new to HTML / plotly and can't track down an error message or any reason interactivity isn't supported so cannot give a more specific question.

Could anyone provide guidance on:

1. Getting more details from my html doc (developer tools?)
   or
2. A way to enable interactivity
   or
3. This is simply impossible and I need to try something different.

NOTES:

1. Any solution must have the option to hide specific input cells.
2. On further research this **may** not be possible: [How to get ipywidgets interact to work in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463702/how-to-get-ipywidgets-interact-to-work-in-html)

Thank you,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to export the whole notebook, or just the graph?

The (self-contained) interactive graph can be exported using plotly:

```
fig.write_html("myplot.html")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to export the entire notebook as it will contain markdown cells in addition to the graph

Answer (score 0):

If you export notebook to static HTML you will lost interactivity of widgets. The `ipywidgets` needs to be connected to Python kernel.

What you can do is to try export notebook to web application, you have two options:

1. Mercury ([GitHub](https://github.com/mljar/mercury), [docs](https://runmercury.com/docs/))
2. Voila ([GitHub](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila), [docs](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/))

Mercury is simpler than Voila, there are no callbacks, cells are automatically re-executed. The Voila works with `ipywidgets`. You can self-host both apps, additionally Mercury offers Cloud service.